# EF Core: encrypt table column for certain user roles only

Tags: c#, encryption, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am working on a startup project in .NET Core, with using the Entity Framework Core, version 1.1. It is a typical ASP.NET Core MVC application, with three roles: user, basic admin and super admin. Due to budget and customer requirements, both types of admin roles will have direct access to the database.

Now, one of the fields each User table has is SecurityAnswer, which is the correct response to a security question. The answer should be visible and editable only by the user himself and the super admin. Due to basic admins' direct access to the database, this cannot be handled in the application layer and the data have to be encrypted also in the database. I have seen several similar posts on StackOverflow, but all of them solve my problem only partially.

My questions are:

- How do I encrypt/decrypt data only for a particular user/user role?
- Where do I securely store the encryption/decryption key?

Comment: "Where do I securely store the encryption/decryption key?" - under the 3rd flowerpot on the right. This is the Achilles heel of all encrypted data schemes.